# Vulkan - How to efficiently copy data to CPU *and* wait for it

Tags: vulkan

Let's say I want to execute the following commands:

```
cmd_buff start
dispatch (write to texture1)
copy (texture1 on gpu to buffer1 host-visible)
dispatch (write to texture2)
cmd_buff end
```

I'd like to know as soon as possible when buffer1's data are available.

My idea here is to have a waiting thread on which I'd wait for the copy to have completed. What I'd do is first split the above list of cmds into:

```
cmd_buff_1 start
dispatch (write to texture1)
copy (texture1 on gpu to buffer1 host-visible)
cmd_buff_1 end
```

and:

```
cmd_buff_2 start
dispatch (write to texture2)
cmd_buff_2 end
```

Now, I'd call vkQueueSubmit with cmd_buff_1 and with some fence1, followed by a call to another vkQueueSubmit with cmd_buff_2 with NULL fence.

On the waiting thread I'd call vkWaitForFences( fence1 ).

That's how I see such an operation. However, I'm wondering if that is optimal and if there was actually any way to put a direct sync still within cmd_buff_1 so that I wouldn't need to split the cmd buffer into two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never break up submit operations just to test fences; submit operations are too heavyweight to do that. If the CPU needs to check to see if work on the GPU has reached a specific point, there are many options other than a fence.

The simplest mechanism for something like this is to use an event. Set the event after the transfer operation, then use `vkGetEventStatus` on the CPU to see when it is ready. That's a polling function, so a waiting CPU thread won't immediately wake up when the data is ready (but then, there's no guarantee that would happen with a non-polling function either).

If timeline semaphores are available to you, you can wait for them to reach a particular counter value on the CPU with `vkWaitSemaphores`. This requires that you break the batch up into two batches, but they can both be submitted in the same submit command.

Comment: Ok so the samephore case.
Assuming I have two command buffers and want to submit them with one vkQueueSubmit.
vkQueueSubmit takes as argument a list of command buffers and a list of semaphores (to signal and to wait), but how is order of those determined? How do I tell the GPU, in vkQueueSubmit, that the semaphore is to be signaled in-between the two command buffers?

Comment: @maxest: "*vkQueueSubmit takes as argument a list of command buffers and a list of semaphores*" No, it takes a list of *batches*, as defined by a `VkSubmitInfo` structure. Each batch has "a list of command buffers and a list of semaphores"

Comment: Ah, I see. So I could create two batches. The first one takes the first command buffer and the said semaphore passed as the signal semaphore. The second submit takes the second cmd buffer. I suppose the semaphore is not required for the second batch to be passed as wait semephore?

Comment: @maxest: Are you trying to read the results of the transfer operation from the CPU or from a GPU operation? Because your question was about a CPU read, so the process waiting on it needs to be on the CPU.

Comment: I want to read on the CPU, yes. That's why I think wait semaphore does not need to be set on the second batch.

Comment: I'd have one more question regarding this problem. I've read there is often a transfer-specific queue available. Let's say I'd like to have the copy operation done to that queue. In that case I need to call two vkQueueSubmit, and use semaphores to sync among those three cmd buffers, right? The transfer cmd buffer would wait for a semaphore which cmd_buff_1 would need to signal. Is this correct? I assume one can use the same semaphore to sync among different queues?

Comment: Regarding `vkGetEventStatus`, there is a GitHub issue where you state in comments that the presented idea in this answer may doesn't really work: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/755. Is it cleared up since then?

Comment: @plasmacel: I didn't respond in that issue. But the conclusion of it seems to be that you can busy-wait on an event.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry, don't know why but I confused you with krOoze. Anyway, yeah you can busy-wait on the host for an event, however it is still not clear to me whether the `vkGetEventStatus` call properly introduces the required memory dependency - this is the problem in which the linked issue was inconclusive - if it is implementation dependent then it is possible that your busy wait results in a much longer than actually needed loop, or even in an infinite loop. I really don't know.